# Wrote a money order and added the recipient line, but won't be using it, can I change to myself?

Tags: money-order

I just bought a money order and then found out I don't need it.  It is not a lot and even less than processing fee at Western Union.  Can I still get the money back.  Can I add my name to the recipient and sign the money order to myself?  All that would be suspicious is that the recipient line is marked out and I changed it to my name.

Answer (score 3):

You can (usually) take it to your bank, and with appropriate identification, endorse the check with the words, "not used for the purpose intended." The one time I needed to not-use a money order, I was instructed to do so by the cashier/clerk at the bank.